# Crear FUNCTION plpgsql

Tags: php, postgresql-9.3

necesito si me pueden ayudar con esto, tengo un query que si lo ejecuto en mi bbdd me trae el resultado que necesito, pero mi problema es pasar dicho código a una funcion, nunca he creado funciones, me podrían ayudar a como realizarlo

```
    SELECT id, count(asistir) as total_asistencia,
        sum(CASE WHEN asistir = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS presente,
        sum(CASE WHEN asistir = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS inasistente
      FROM ASISTENCIA
  WHERE validacion=1 and id=1273
group by id
```

Anexo imagen de lo que me trae la bbdd, y mi dilema es como crear la funcion, ayuda por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo tengo algo hecho, pero se que me falta codigo por incorporar, porque me imagino que algo debo declarar y algo me debe retornar, dejo lo que he realizado, he modificado mi tabla a una vista, que me trae los mismos datos de la imagen, pero cuando la ejecuto me arroja el siguiente error:

**Error de SQL:
ERROR:  type interger does not exist**

```
    CREATE TYPE rowtype_diastrabajados AS (
    id INTEGER,
    total_asistencia INTEGER,
    presente INTEGER,
    inasistente INTEGER
);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dias_trabajados(xid interger) RETURNS SETOF rowtype_diastrabajados 

LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
    DECLARE
        r rowtype_diastrabajados;
    BEGIN
    res.id:=xidalupro;

       SELECT total_asistencia INTO r.total_asistencia, presente INTO r.presente, inasistencia INTO inasistente FROM view_asistencia WHERE id=xid

        IF r.total_asistencia IS NULL THEN
            r.total_asistencia :=0;
    END IF;

    IF r.presente IS NULL THEN
            r.presente:=0;
    END IF;

    IF r.inasistente IS NULL THEN
            r.inasistente:=0;
    END IF;


RETURN r;
END;
$$;
```

---

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dias_trabajados(xid int) 
RETURNS TABLE(ida integer, tot integer, present integer, ausent integer) AS 
$$   
BEGIN

SELECT id, total_asistencia, presente, inasistencia  FROM view_asistencia WHERE id=xid

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: La documentación está [aquí](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-createfunction.html). Dale un intento. PD. La versión 9.3 de PGSQL ya no tiene soporte, piensa en usar una más reciente :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, acabo de editar mi pregunta, ingresando lo que yo he realizado, pero se que hay cosas que me faltan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tu función, sólo falta definir que retorne todos los campos de tu consulta. Entiendo que es sólo una fila:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_dias_trabajados(xid int) 
RETURNS TABLE(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int) AS 
$$   
BEGIN

SELECT id, count(asistir) as total_asistencia,
    sum(CASE WHEN asistir = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS presente,
    sum(CASE WHEN asistir = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS inasistente
FROM ASISTENCIA
WHERE validacion=1 and id=xid
GROUP BY id

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Y así debería estar definida tu función. Después, podrías hacer un [sanitize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17865708/236345) para el parámetro de entrada si es necesario, etc...

Comment: Amigo, muchas gracias, he modificado mi funcion y he editado mi codigo, pero algo estoy haciendo mal, porque me arroja error  type interger does not exist :'(

Comment: @JuanjoMedina Ponle `int` a ese parámetro de entrada, entonces :)

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia  @Alfabravo, ese int en qué parámetro de entrada get_dias_trabajados(xid interger), en este?

Comment: @JuanjoMedina así es.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, fuiste de gran ayuda, para ser mi primera vez en funciones y entender la logica de esto.  Acabo de publicar mi codigo real con el cual traigo el resultado de la bbdd

Comment: Solo me queda una duda, tengo mi query SELECT id, total_asistencia, presente, inasistencia  FROM view_asistencia WHERE id=xid, es posible dentro de la misma funcion sacar el promedio (presente * 100)/inasistencia , me imagino que si, pero no se como declararlo porque esa variable no la tengo en mi vista

Comment: @JuanjoMedina preguntas si puedes añadir otro campo en el SELECT? Pues sí puedes; en el RETURN TABLE añades un campo que debería ser de tipo `decimal` o `numeric`

Comment: Si amigo, lo hice como me orientaste, muchas gracias

Comment: Solo me ha surgido un detalle, si mi SELECT id, total_asistencia, presente, inasistencia, round(presente*100)/total_asistencia FROM view_asistencia WHERE id=xid, llegar con este resultado (111, 0,0,0, 0), pero al ejecutar la funcion  me arroja este error ERROR:  division by zero
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_dias_trabajados(integer) line 4 at RETURN QUERY